# error: no suitable method found for add(String,Class<RouteRequestManagerFragment>)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Thank; i am new to Android Studio and java,but i tried as much i can also did google,but i couldn't, plz anyone can help me to solve this error.
Please help me! I get this error for build java code in Android Studio: no suitable method found for add(String,Class).

```
package com.uit.huydaoduc.hieu.chi.hhapp.Main.Driver.v2;

import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.uit.huydaoduc.hieu.chi.hhapp.Main.Driver.v2.RouteRequestManagerFragment;
import com.uit.huydaoduc.hieu.chi.hhapp.R;
import com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout;
import com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.utils.v4.FragmentPagerItemAdapter;
import com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.utils.v4.FragmentPagerItems;
//import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import cn.bingoogolapple.titlebar.BGATitleBar;


public class DriverActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements RouteRequestManagerFragment.OnRouteRequestManagerFragmentListener{

    BGATitleBar titleBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);

        FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                .add("Your routes", RouteRequestManagerFragment.class)
                .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);

        Init();
        Event();
    }

    private void Init() {
        titleBar = (BGATitleBar) findViewById(R.id.titlebar);
    }

    private void Event() {
        titleBar.setDelegate(new BGATitleBar.Delegate() {
            @Override
            public void onClickLeftCtv() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClickTitleCtv() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClickRightCtv() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClickRightSecondaryCtv() {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

I got this code like *grab and ubber* for

> find a car

. But, when I build it got some error
Help me plase!!! **Im beginning for java and android app.**

Comment: Please share the implementation of FragmentPagerItemAdapter. I am assuming from your error that it does not have an Add method.

Comment: This is my implementation: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

Comment: And this: implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

Comment: And implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'

    // login activity
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.2@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.6.0@aar'

    // Location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

Comment: implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

Comment: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    // more...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'       // support design
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'     // material edittext
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'     // custom font for all view

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'

Comment: implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'

    // action bar
    implementation 'cn.bingoogolapple:bga-titlebar:1.0.8'

    // radius button
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'

    // Date & Time picker
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.0'

Comment: It's best that you edit your question with all these comments

Comment: implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    // recycler view
    implementation 'com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:2.9.38'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.1.0'

    // alert dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    // Top right menu
    implementation 'com.zaaach:toprightmenu:1.1.2'

    // Header For layout
    implementation 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshLayout:1.1.0-alpha-5'
    implementation 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshHeader:1.1.0-alpha-5'

Comment: implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'lib.kingja.switchbutton:switchbutton:1.1.7'

    // Hieu
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'

Comment: implementation 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'

    //Hung
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.+'

Answer (score 0):

This statement throws the error:

```
FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
    getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
    .add("Your routes", RouteRequestManagerFragment.class)
    .create());
```

`add()` function looks like this:
abstract fun add(element: E): Boolean
OR
abstract fun add(index: Int, element: E)
[doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html)

And `"Your routes"` is not of type `Int`

Comment: I changed to .add(10, RouteRequestManagerFragment.class), but, its still error: no suitable method found for add(int,Class<RouteRequestManagerFragment>)

Answer (score 0):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uit.huydaoduc.hieu.chi.hhapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //Manager/place
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'

    // login activity
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.2@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.6.0@aar'

    // Location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

    // for firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

    // Facebook, Google login support is required
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    // more...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'       // support design
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'     // material edittext
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'     // custom font for all view
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'

    // process bar
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'

    // action bar
    implementation 'cn.bingoogolapple:bga-titlebar:1.0.8'

    // radius button
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'

    // Date & Time picker
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.0'

    // loading view
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    // recycler view
    implementation 'com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:2.9.38'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.1.0'

    // alert dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    // Top right menu
    implementation 'com.zaaach:toprightmenu:1.1.2'

    // Header For layout
    implementation 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshLayout:1.1.0-alpha-5'
    implementation 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshHeader:1.1.0-alpha-5'

    // Tab
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'lib.kingja.switchbutton:switchbutton:1.1.7'

    // Hieu
    implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'

    //about
    implementation 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'

    //Hung
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.+'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.7.0@aar'

}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my build.gradle